# Passing variables and multiple Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x

I have three classes as shown below:

```
class abc():
  def __init__(self):
    self.expiry_date = None
  def some_print():
     print(self.expiry_date)

class zxc(abc):
    def __init__(self, expiry_date):
        self.expiry_date = expiry_date
        abc.__init__()
    def some():
        self.some_print()

class xyz(abc):
    def __init__():
       abc.__init__()
    def cute():
      self.expiry_date = date.today()
      z = zxc(self.expiry_date)
      z.some()
```

What I am trying to do is pass the variable expiry_date from class `xyz` to the class `zxc`. Class `xyz` creates an instance of `abc` so the `expiry_date` variable defined in the constructor of the class `abc` gets updated. Since, I am creating a new object of class `zxc` which initializes `abc` this variable is `None` again.

Is there any way I can pass `expiry_date` from `xyz` to `zxc` while updating the constructor variable in `abc`?

So, when I call `z.some()` I want it to print today's date.

Comment: Why is the obvious `z = zxc(self.expiry_date)` not a possibility for you?

Comment: @SeanVieira I actually missed that. But, even if I do that, that wouldn't update the init value of `expiry_date` in `abc`. So, it still will print `None`. I've updated the question.

Comment: @SeanVieira One of the most brain dead moments for me. If I move the `abc.__init__` line before the `self.expiry_date = expiry_date` in `class zxc` then it'll work.

Comment: Yeah, it's not that your variable isn't being set, it's that you then go and unset it.

Comment: @NathanielFord thanks lol. You mind putting that as an answer? I am debating whether I should delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is captured in the following lines:

```
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.expiry_date = None

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, expiry_date):
        self.expiry_date = expiry_date
        A.__init__()
```

First, when `B` gets instantiated it sets it's member field `expiry_date` to the value passed in. Then, it calls the super class `__init__()` (which for the record, you can use `super().__init__()`). Then, in `A`, the member field for `expiry_date` is set to `None`. This is why it appears as though `B` is not setting that value - it is, but then it's being removed.